# How to Add JavaScript Library into Static Web or PHP Projects in Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

I use a clean installation of Eclipse PHP 2023-09 on Windows 10. The plugin Wild Web Development is installed and enabled. How to add my own JavaScript Libraries into a project? Some solutions talk about "JavaScript Resources" and "User Library" but I can't find them in this release. It seems all these solutions are old and don't work for this release.

Comment: If just adding the file(s) of your own JavaScript libraries into the project is not enough (also the project type/nature should not matter), please explain your issue with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).